# Way is my code showing the output before getting all inputs?

Tags: ruby, bubble-sort

I'm creating a program that asks for number of inputs needed, and then bubbles sort these inputs. 
my code:

```
def bubble_sort(list)
       sl = list.clone
       sl.each_index do |i|
         ( sl.length - i - 1 ).times do |j|
             if ( sl[j+1] < sl[j] )
                 sl[j], sl[j+1] = sl[j+1], sl[j]
             end
         end
       end
end
puts "Enter Number of Elements"
n = gets.chomp 
puts "Enter #{n} elements" 
n.to_i.times do 
(list ||= []) << gets.chomp
bubble_sort(list)
p ('Sorted elements:')
p (list)
end
```

I have tested the bubbling loop and it's working fine. The problem that I have is with the output, the program asks for each input in a new line, but whenever I entered any input, it shows the output immediately and it doesn't wait for inputting the other elements. Can someone help me out of how to fix my to make the program hold the output until it finishes from all inputs?

Answer (score 3):

You put the `p(list)` (as well as the `bubble_sort(list)` and a ton of other stuff) in your element-gathering loop. If you don't want them done as part of the loop, you should put them outside.

Answer (score 1):

Because you tell your machine to do so. Try:

```
list = []
n.to_i.times do 
  list << gets.chomp
end

bubble_sort(list)
p ('Sorted elements:')
p (list)
```

Instead of:

```
n.to_i.times do 
  (list ||= []) << gets.chomp
  bubble_sort(list)
  p ('Sorted elements:')
  p (list)
end
```

Comment: @user3467152 - just use `puts` instead of `p`.